# How to hand over a Visual Studio program with a database connection?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, virtual-machine

After a huge amount of searching I haven't found any information about how to hand over a web project based on entity framework with an SQL Server database connection. The company I do the project for, said I have to give them the whole project to test, but the problem is that I don't know how to give it to them.

If anyone has an instruction for me on how to hand them the project and how they have to install it, it would be very nice. At first I got the project with a test database in a VMware file. I coded the whole program in there as well. But I can't just hand them the VM back in again.

Comment: I certainly hope you've added your source code to *some kind* of source control system! (like Github or so) ..... you could just share a link to that source code repository with them ...

Comment: yeah the complete Code is on Github, the big problem is, that the database got changed so they need that one as well. Also the Company leader wants a complete installation guide from me. My first Idea was to zip the whole program an add a copy of the database backup file. The problem is the connection between the Database and the programm and the IIS Express.

Comment: So script out the database from SSMS and include that script in the source code repo as well ....

Comment: is there a way to hand over the whole project without Github or something like this?

Comment: Grab the current code from Github, script out the database structure and any necessary "seed" data - and zip up the whole directory of source code (C# and SQL) and send them a ZIP file ...

Comment: The aim is to be able to deploy a system from source control; all the project's artifacts should be in github.

Comment: @marc_s so if the company unzips the file, will they be able to start everything without much effort? I don't know if the connection will still be there, or if i have to send them an instruction on how to connect the SQL-Server to the Visual-Studio Project and get ready to start the whole thing with IIS-Express.

Comment: Well, they' ll need to re-create the database and run the SQL scripts, they'll need to ensure that the connection from your app to the database works .....

Comment: But if i send them a backup from the Database so they could simply import it back? This way the don't have to run the scripts and just need to set up the database connection. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume what your clients want it to test the web application and not to be in possession the source code.

It thus the case, you can install **ngrok** on your machine which can then tunnel your localhost application to public accessible application.

Have a look at https://ngrok.com/

Comment: They also want the source code, it's the final handover, so they want everything to check.